# Open a link in a https page in a new http page

Tags: http, https, hyperlink

My site contains both unsecure and secure content and I have a link to 'Research' that is required in http and https. Is there a way, when clicking on the link in the secure area, to open it in a new tab/window, retaining one https window and a new http one?

Research and secure have different menus and the security is causing the wrong menu to display.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your link target="_blank" like this:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank">Clikc here</a>
```

But you don't get https because, it contains unsecure content.

Comment: I think it is a quirk of how our CMS publisher has been created, as a secure menu seems to override an unsecure one. I think I will just have to remove the functionality :(